# npm install error: "Host key verification failed"

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am trying to run `npm install` in a new Angular app. I am running it behind a corporate firewall, which is obviously the issue.

I am running into errors specifically with the `pemrouz/buble` package, which is a dependency of a dependency. One of Angular's dependencies is explicitly specifying that buble be downloaded using SSH. Originally, the SSH connection was getting blocked, but I was able to convince the network group to allow the connection.

However, it's still being proxied, which is messing up SSL stuff.

I can `git clone` the package by specifying that git not use strict SSL, but NPM ignores this setting.
I can also specify that NPM not use strict SSL, which allows HTTPS connections to work properly -- but apparently this also doesn't apply to SSH.

I am not using Docker or Chocolatey (this seems to be the common source of the issue for other people seeing this error).

I have seen the other questions, on StackOverflow and elsewhere, where people have had this issue, but the answer is always "you're running an old version of NPM." However, I am running 6.14.4, which appears to be the latest. Besides, I don't see how that could cause a host key issue?

How can I get NPM to make the SSH connection without using strict SSL? Or otherwise, how can I fix the host key verification issue?

Thanks!

EDIT: I ran `ssh git@github.com` and it prompted me "do you want to trust this?" and I said yes -- now it's showing the error "Permission denied (publickey)" when I run `npm install`.

This is not a private repo, it's the public repo at https://github.com/pemrouz/buble.